# Can I load Fixed Width files into an Oracle Autonomous Database?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I have data in large Fixed Width files and am looking to load that into an Oracle Autonomous Database (Autonomous Data Warehouse). I don't see Fixed Width Files mentioned in the documentation for loading data. What would the best way be to load data from Fixed Width files? Are Fixed Width Files supported by DBMS_CLOUD (either COPY_DATA or CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE)?

Comment: I do not use Oracle Autonomous Database , but a quick cheek shows its ability to use SQL*Loader. You might want to take a look at the documentation on its [Fixed Record Format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-concepts.html#GUID-B88C4284-089D-4565-AFAF-6A73122AAA0B).

Answer (score 0):

You can use DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE to load data from a fixed-width source file to an external table in the Oracle Autonomous Database. From there you can do anything you wish, e.g., you could create a regular table, move all / selected data, perform ETL, etc.

For the Autonomous Database use Database Actions section and within the Development / Launchpad select the SQL tile / SQL Worksheet.

A brief example is provided below (sourced from documentation, but abbreviated).

```
BEGIN DBMS_CLOUD.CREATE_EXTERNAL_TABLE(
             table_name      => '<YOUR_TABLE_NAME>'
,            credential_name => '<YOUR_CREDENTIAL_NAME>'
,            file_uri_list   => '<YOUR_ORACLE_OBJECT_STORE_URL>'
,            format          => json_object('trimspaces' value 'rtrim','skipheaders' value '1', 'dateformat' value 'YYYYMMDD')
,            field_list      => 'object_id      (1:3)   char
                               , object_name    (4:14)  char
                               , object_type    (15:39)  char’
,            column_list     => 'object_id      number
                               , object_name    varchar2(30)
                               , object_type    varchar2(25)’);
END;
/
```

Refer to the Autonomous Database documentation for more details.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/load-data-cloud-examples.html#GUID-ED442E4C-9B4C-4A51-98AF-3BD7C8D68BF0

Answer (score -1):

This is possible using the general text/JSON handling capabilities of DBMS_CLOUD.

For an example, see the documentation here:

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/load-data-cloud-examples.html#GUID-A96BC35C-965D-4F38-8CBC-7484B50ECD39

Comment: This is a link-only answer. You should quote the relevant text from the link so that the content is not "in another castle" and so the answer still makes sense if the link dies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).